# Changing Databases Dynamically using Variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want change into a database programatically using in code:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @DBName sysname

SET @DBName= 'foo'
SET @SQL = 'USE [' + @DBName + ']'

select @SQL
execute @SQL
```

When I execute the @SQL I get this error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
>   The name 'USE [foo]' is not a valid identifier.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

The goal is to now be in the foo database after this runs.

Comment: Always use QUOTENAME(databaseName) to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Related SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/727788/73226

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
execute @SQL
```

to

```
exec (@SQL)
```

and it worked for me. However, the scope of the use is only in the dynamic SQL.

Comment: It works because that's the syntax of [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.90).aspx) (when using dynamic sql strings, not procedures). The initial statement would've worked only if @sql was the name of a stored procedure without params.

Comment: When I run this I am in the master db, after I run this, I am still in the master DB. Shouldn't I be in the DB called 'Datasets'?

Comment: @Max No. The scope gets reset when the `exec` finishes. So you end up back where you started. To use this approach all your remaining code would also need to be appended after the `use`.